# AWS CloudFront + single S3 bucket + multiple subdomains on xyz.cloudfront.net

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I try to connect multiple subdomains (wildcard would be the best) to single S3 bucket. I don't have my own domain, I want to do it with automatically generated `xyz.cloudfront.net`, e.g.

```
> sub1.xyz.cloudfront.net 
> sub2.xyz.cloudfront.net
> sub3.xyz.cloudfront.net
```

should be mapped to the same S3 bucket.

I know how to connect S3 bucket to `xyz.cloudfront.net`.
How to connect multiple subdomains to this bucket?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: @JamesDean My app is in development. I want to test using it on multiple subdomains e.g. sub1.<cloudfrontId>.cloudfront.net, sub2.<cloudfrontId>.cloudfront.net without buying domain.

Comment: you don't control over cloudfront.net domain , you can create multiple distributions , aws doesn't charge for creating multiple distributions and you can get different  name for which you can test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create a sub domain on the default cloudfront domains, since you don't control the DNS or certificates for the cloudfront domains.